# grab UNIX timestamp down to the last second

Tags: python-3.x, unix-timestamp, python-datetime

How would I grab the exact Unix time in python3?

```
import time
t = (time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

For example I can use the code above and plug that into a converter. But this does not work for what I need because there is no output to hours and seconds

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `time.strftime`? There are more formats available than the one you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Time.Time() you can grab the exact UNIX timestamp